# Sitecore URL not working after installation

Tags: installation, sitecore9

I have installed sitecore 9 xp0 in my local machine. After the installation, when I tried to launch the URL, the url is automatically redirecting to https. But in IIS, sitecore has only http binding.

These are the below lines from powershell during installation. It clearly shows http binding is used and it works.

[UpdateSolrSchema]:[Authenticating] http://mywebsite/sitecore/admin/PopulateManagedSchema.aspx?indexes=all
[UpdateSolrSchema]:[Requesting] http://mywebsite/sitecore/admin/PopulateManagedSchema.aspx?indexes=all
[UpdateSolrSchema]:[Success] Completed Request

when I try to launch http://mywebsite/sitecore it is redirecting to https://mywebsite/sitecore and  getting the below error.
Can’t connect securely to this page
This might be because the site uses outdated or unsafe TLS security settings. If this keeps happening, try contacting the website’s owner.

I even added https binding manually, selecting "DO_NOT_TRUST_SitecoreRootCert". But I am getting the below error

This site is not secure
This might mean that someone’s trying to fool you or steal any info you send to the server. You should close this site immediately.

Not sure, what could be the issue. Can someone help me on this? Thanks in Advance

Comment: For local no need to use https for Sitecore cms, there should also be no redirect, found out why it's redirection you. solr and xConnect must be on https.  or do you want to run Sitecore on https? and searching for a solution to get a valid certificate?

Comment: I suggest going through the configuration files specified in this how-to, which will validate a reason for redirecting to https. You'll also want to try incognito mode as Chrome can cache a redirect to https from http, and also turn off identity server if it's running on your local and you don't want to use it, as the fall back scenario will be to just log in directly to Sitecore.  https://www.sitecorefundamentals.com/providing-external-access-for-the-xp-single-developer-installation